# Using Laplace transform method, solve $y'''- 3y'' + y' - y = t^2e^{2t}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace, laplace-method

> Using Laplace transform method, solve 
>   $$\dfrac {d^3y}{dt^3} - 3\dfrac {d^2y}{dt^2} + \dfrac {dy}{dt} - y = t^2e^{2t}$$ 
>   given $y (0) = 1, y′(0) = 0, y′′(0) = –2$.

I'm not able to factorize once the differential equation is formed.Can someone help me out?
[I was able to solve till here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wag3t.jpg)

Comment: Looking at the graph of the cubic denominator generated it has one real none integer root. Perhaps there is an error in the question ?

Comment: Usually, you would appeal to partial fractions decomposition. It would be good to see your computation for $Y(s)$ or $F(s)$ for which you would then search for its inverse Laplace transform.

Comment: I've added my solved part above

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct DE, ...... the solution is rathe rbig and complicated....

Comment: If that was +y on the end everything would be fine...

Answer (score 1):

Note that the Laplace transform of the LHS is given by:

$$s^3Y(s)-s^2y(0)-sy'(0)-y''(0)-3(s^2Y(s)-sy(0)-y'(0))+$$
$$sY(s)-y(0)-Y(s)\tag1$$

And for the RHS:

$$\frac{2}{(s-2)^3}\tag2$$

Comment: The second "LHS" is "RHS"?

Comment: Yes I was able to get till here can you check the image I've uploaded

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with factorization of the polynomial on LHS:
$$F(s)(s^3-3s^2+s-1)=\dfrac 2 {(s-2)^3}+s^2-3s-1$$
Since $s^3-3s^2+s-1$ has two complex roots and a real root that is not an integer. Are you sure the DE is correct and the inital conditions are correct ?

WA gives a [very complicated answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27%27-3y%27%27%2By%27-y%3D0) for the homogeneous DE.